# NoMethodError in Flights#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controllers

Showing app/views/flights/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.name

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <p>
2:  <b>Airline Name:</b>

3:  <%= @flight.airline.name %>
```

well the above error is occurring when am trying to submit the 'seat' form.

I have a '_new_seat' 'partial' page in my flights/show. when clicking on 'book new seat'(submit),
it should redirect to seats/show, but it doesn't..

whether it requires an extra method in flights controller?.. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@flight` does not have an `airline` associated.

To get off the error when there is no `airline` associated, write:

```
@flight.airline.try(:name)
```

To have an `airline` associated. check your `@flight` object properties.

First, check you have this:

```
class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :airline
```

Second, you have `airline_id` correctly set in flight instance.

Third, you have an airline with that `airline_id` saved in airlines table.

Comment: well i made those associations...       airline-> :has_many :flights   flight-> belongs_to :airline    and seat-> belongs_to :flight

Comment: well i have all those correctly.. the problem is occuring when trying to create a seat not flight..

Comment: does `@flight.airline.try(:name)` make your page after the form appear?

Comment: your error message is telling another thing, however you can also be having the problem you are mentioning.

Comment: If you change your line to `@flight.airline.try(:name)`, what happens?

Comment: well yes.. i confused with the error message... it is not related to my problem...

Comment: well if i add @flight.airline.try(:name) i cant even create a flight now.. it is showing nomethod error...

Comment: no method error should be in another place, can you show trace?

Comment: does my seat model requies an extra association.. like seat-> belongs_to :alirline.. ?

Comment: weel this the trace for the error(@flight.airline.try(:name)                  NoMethodError in Flights#show

Showing app/views/flights/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

NoMethodError

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <p>
2:  <b>Airline Name:</b>
3:  <%= @flight.airline.try(:name) %>
4: </p>
5: 
6: <p>

Comment: I think, you need to rewrite your question to show the real problem to solve. For example writing important parts of the code and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Print airline `<%= p @flight.airline %>`, it should show airline id and other fields.